# Excel VBA random string

Tags: excel, vba

i need some help in Excel VBA. So i want a random question get in to a cell, but there are mostly things in the internet about int and i got a string. I tried it with an array but cant continue. Do you know an answer?

Picture:
https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-3c4354-1584039544.png.html
PictureCode:
https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-5cb222-1584039888.png.html

On the picture "Fragen" means questions and "Antworten" answer. If i click on "Neue Frage" it should do a random question of the 3

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code as text, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do...

```
[c8] = [CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),"Q1","Q2","Q3")]
```

Of if you really want the questions in an array...

```
Dim q
q = Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
[c8] = q(Int(3 * Rnd))
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Do you know how i avoid duplicate questions?

Comment: So, not random after all?

Comment: If you mean random, but each random question can only display once, that is a completely different scenario. Please ask another question.